# using import dataStructures.jl

Tags: dictionary, julia, sorteddictionary

I am using the dataStructures.jl package. The documentation online states that once created a dictionaries

```
dict = DataStructures.SortedDict{Int64, Int64}
```

I should be able to insert key-value pairs into the data structure by the function, for example

```
insert!(dict, 10, 100)
```

but I keep getting the error

```
ERROR: MethodError: `insert!` has no method matching insert!(
::Type{DataStructures.SortedDict{Int64,Int64,Ord<:Base.Order.Ordering}}, ::Int64, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
 insert!{T}(::Array{T,1}, ::Integer, ::Any)
 insert!(::BitArray{1}, ::Integer, ::Any)
 insert!(::PyCall.PyVector{T}, ::Integer, ::Any)
```

Why is this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've created a datatype, not a dictionary:

```
julia> using DataStructures

julia> dict = DataStructures.SortedDict{Int64, Int64}
DataStructures.SortedDict{Int64,Int64,Ord<:Base.Order.Ordering}

julia> typeof(dict)
DataType
```

—the error message is saying "Don't call this function with a type as the first argument, there's no method for that."

I think this is what you want:

```
julia> dict = SortedDict(["a" => 1, "b" => 2])
DataStructures.SortedDict{String,Int64,Base.Order.ForwardOrdering} with 2 entries:
  "a" => 1
  "b" => 2

julia> typeof(dict)
DataStructures.SortedDict{String,Int64,Base.Order.ForwardOrdering}
```

Comment: DataStructures.jl could probably make it a little easier to construct an empty `SortedDict`.  This definition would do the trick: `(::Type{SortedDict{T,S}}){T,S}() = SortedDict{T,S,Base.Order.ForwardOrdering}()`.  This will allow `SortedDict{Int,Int}()` as you might expect would work.